# Create a shortcut to users desktop and enable it for offline files, through script or GP

Tags: windows, group-policy, scripting

What I would like to do is have a shortcut on the desktop of all users that takes them to a network folder containing files.  Easy enough to do.  The part I am wanting to add on is to set it for offline files.  So the shortcut gets created and automatically gets added to offline files for sync during log on and log off without admin or user intervention.

Manually, easy enough to do, but I don't want to do manually 200 users.  So I would like to use either our login script or group policy.

As I said, I know how to have the shortcut added easy through a script or gp, it's the automatically enabling it for offline files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like a windows question, is that correct?  Please add that info for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, you have a couple of scripting options.

Windows XP/2003 : [csccmd](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884739) utility
Windows Vista/7 : use WMI and PowerShell ([example scripts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/06/03/how-can-i-enable-and-disable-offline-files.aspx))

If you'd like to use Group Policy, you can make use of the User-based policies under User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files and add specific UNC paths to **[Administratively assigned offline files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978568.aspx)**

Comment: excellent, thank you!  I set it, so let's hope it works...